# Can't collect data from WCF

Tags: wcf

My problem is that when downloading data from a webservice, say 1250 records, everything works as it should be (done in 30 seconds), but when i wants to get 1300 records , my method works indefinitely (it's ends after 10 minutes with timeout). I tested the sql query and the query itself executes quickly(also tested in wcf service by debugging), but when there is data transfer everything slows down.
This is my web config binding:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="soapUniglobShopService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="4000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="4000000"
    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <security mode="None">
    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

I dont know what should i change in web config to get this records or maybe i should change something in IIS , i dont know.

***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___
SOLUTION FOUND ON PAGE : http://ardalis.com/fixing-maxitemsinobjectgraph-quota-error-in-wcf-service**

Best regards
Marcel

Comment: Did you check to ensure that the max settings are the same for the wcf service config as they are for the client application?

Comment: Try setting all the max sizes to 2147483647. Including the readerQuotas on both client and service. Restart the service and try your application again. If it works then it's a config issue.

Comment: I added on all max values and i have exception now : "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected
error occurred on a receive." I tried to get one string from one method and works fine with this parameters.

Comment: That's a very generic exception. Are there any inner exceptions?

Comment: I restarted iis and exception changed: "An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
response to http://mydomain/wcf.svc. This could
be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol.
This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by
the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server
logs for more details."

Comment: That's also a very generic error but it's most likely happening due to configuration issues on the server. You will have to do tracing in order to pin-point the underlying problem. Check out the trace tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx

Comment: Did it fix your problem?

Comment: grr i delete comment ... no it dont i have another exception

Comment: What does the other exception say?

Comment: it saying now this paramater maxItemsInObjectGraph is too big it can be only 65536 i changed to it but my exception changed for previous exception;/

Comment: Read this: http://ardalis.com/fixing-maxitemsinobjectgraph-quota-error-in-wcf-service

Comment: I checkd last your last post and i works great !! Thank you !!

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file required higher max values in order to process the larger data set. After which you still had a problem of the maxItemsInObjectGraph which also had to be increased. The problem that you ran into which said that "maxItemsInObjectGraph is too big it can be only 65536" after you increased it's size, meant that you needed to make sure that the client and service values were the same. In fact, this goes for all the configuration settings, the service and client values have to match for the binding to work properly.

Comment: Please post the full details here.  If someone finds this question in the future, it will be more convenient to see it in the accepted answer.